# Angular Material: Not able to drop on a dynamically created droplist

Tags: angular, angular-material-6, angular-material-7

For some reason (read: Cannot create many components), I have to create sections on my app which will be able to act as drop elements. (cannot use `*ngIf`)

I created DropListRef like -

```
constructor(private dragDropService: DragDrop) {} 

const dropListRef = this.dragDropService
      .createDropList(dropZone)
      .withItems([]);
```

And I am trying to detect whether an element has been dropped as -

```
dropListRef.dropped.subscribe(event => {
      console.log("dropped: ");
});
```

However, I never find the console output.

Link to sample code - 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r3spyc

Link to demo video - 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b6RUuOk9r7s9vFd3NlhgR9ot1hHP1Oeb/view

**Cannot create many components**

1. The way I have written in not atypical with the examples shown on the [Angular official site](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview), however, the same docs advertise an ability to createDropList() [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api) given a native-element. If you inspect it further - the code creates a DropListRef and adds an element to the DOM, however, it does not respond to events such as `dropped`, `entered`. It feels that I am missing some important steps like registering it somewhere or connecting with the other DropList which then Angular Material can recognize or identify it.
2. The reason I cannot create a single component (for example - a `Dropbox component`) because that would be oversimplifying the problem at hand. There are too many complexities associated with the problem to be encapsulated in a single component like the `Dropbox component` (or many). I might just end up creating 100+ ng-templates (or different components) if I go the route of creating a template for each use-case.

Answer (score 0):

The way you code is not a typical way to code for Angular. I looked up the [Angular official site](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) and made a little tweak for you.

I've created a drop-box component with **drop-box.component.html**:

```
<div>{{text}}</div>
```

**drop-box.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "drop-box",
  templateUrl: "./drop-box.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./drop-box.component.scss"]
})
export class DropboxComponent {
  @Input() text = "";
  constructor() {}
}
```

For your **app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import {
  CdkDragDrop,
  CdkDrag,
  DragDropRegistry,
  DragDrop,
  DragRef,
  moveItemInArray,
  transferArrayItem
} from "@angular/cdk/drag-drop";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "angular-draggable";
  previousIndex = 0;

  todo = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
  list = ["default item"];
  isEnabled = false;

  constructor(private dragDropService: DragDrop) {}

  onDragStart(event, i) {
    console.log("drag started!", event);
    console.log('event.previousIndex',event.previousIndex);
    console.log('i',i);
    this.previousIndex = i;
  }

  createDroplist() {
    this.isEnabled = !this.isEnabled;
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>){
    if(this.isEnabled)
    {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        this.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

**Note** that the "Click me to create droplist" button and the createDroplist method is probably not needed anymore. But I put it there to enable/disable the dragging in case you still need it.

And the **app.component.html**:

```html
<div cdkDropListGroup>
  <div class="example-container">
    <h2>To do</h2>

    <div style="position: relative;">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of todo; let i = index">
        <div cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList" class="example-list" [cdkDropListData]="todo" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]">
          <div class="example-box stupid">{{item}}</div>
          <div class="example-box" (cdkDragStarted)="onDragStart($event, i)" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>


  <button (click)="createDroplist()">
    Click me to create droplist
  </button>
  <div id='box' cdkDropList
    #doneList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="list"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList]"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let item of list">
      <drop-box [text]="item"></drop-box>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check out my example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpcwr8). **Again**, to drag from the todo list, you now need to first click the "Click me to create droplist" button, then drop.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, the way I have written in not atypical with the examples shown on the Angular official site, however, the same docs advertise an ability to createDropList here (https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#DragDrop). given a native-element. If you inspect it further - the code creates a DropListRef and adds an element to the DOM, however, it does not respond to events such as dropped, entered. It feels that I am missing some important steps like registering it somewhere which then Angular material can recognize or identify it.

Comment: The reason I cannot create a Dropbox component because that would be oversimplifying the problem at hand. There are too many complexities associated with the problem to be encapsulated in a single component (or many) like Dropbox component.